# Show modal dialog from Win32 app over a UWP application

Tags: c#, winapi, uwp, microsoft-edge, appcontainer

Is there a way for a process to show a modal dialog over a separate process's UWP app (MS Edge in particular) or block any user interaction with a UWP application while we show our dialog?

**Background**

We have an application that from time to time, depending on user actions, should request additional information from the user by showing a modal dialog above a DIFFERENT application, blocking user input while the user interacts with the modal dialog.

With usual Win32 applications we can just show a WinForms modal dialog and set its window owner to the original application and that works fine, e.g.

```
dialog.ShowDialog(GetTargetWindow());
```

However that doesn't work with UWP applications. We tried the same approach, using different hWnds related to the UWP application (like `ApplicationFrameWindow`, `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`, `ApplicationFrameInputSinkWindow` windows) but none seem to work. It looks like that doesn't work because of AppContainer isolation.

It's worth mentioning that this is enterprise software and we have a system service running in the background that can run code any privileges level, so permissions shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) In short: It's legal, but won't work, unless both applications are prepared for this. MS Edge is not prepared to have a cross-process owner/owned window relationship.

Comment: Your design sounds frustrating to the user; they will likely uninstall your program. Why do you need to stop them from using another program?

Comment: Sometimes the world is a frustrating place. Especially in the enterprise.